# Desktop folders won't open with clean install of 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus

I've done a clean install of 18.04 and I can't open desktop folders, not even the desktop trash can. Anybody else had this issue? I click on the desktop folders (double click) and nothing happens.

Strange enough, I can open  them when using Nautilus and going to `home\stackinator\desktop\` or whatever the path is (can't remember at this point).

Answer (score 1):

This was a recent change to Nautilus. You can open the file manager and access Desktop files from there.

I recommend installing Nemo.

Nemo will handle the desktop in lieu of Nautilus.

Enter: `sudo apt-get install nemo`  (.....from the gnome terminal)

or go to the software center and search it.

You can get the deb package from `pkgs.org`

P.S. DO NOT remove Nautilus ...........

Comment: Perhaps it is not wise to allow the user to put directories on their desktop, but not allow them to interact with the directory (open/delete/etc.).

Comment: Not a solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.5 and I confirm I cannot open folders from the desktop. If 'Files' (Nautilus) is started it is possible.
In others words, just start 'Files' then you can open folders from the desktop. Each time a directory is opened from the desktop, a new instance of 'Files' is started... Annoying. You can close all the instances by ctrl + q.